# Prove that there is no function $f$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that there is no function $f$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ such that

$$\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| = \infty$$

*Solution Attempt.*

Another way of formalizing this statement is to say that if $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| < \infty$. Thus, we proceed by contraposition. Suppose

$$\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| = \infty$$

Then it suffices to show that $f$ is not analytic on $\mathbb{D}$. By above, we get that the points $z$ with $|z|=1$ are poles of $f$, i.e. the unit circle. Then $f$ is not differentiable at any point on the unit circle. But none of these are points of $\mathbb{D}$ so this doesn't help. Another idea I had is that

$$\lim_{|z| \to 1} |f(z)| = \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|} = \infty$$

to attempt to obtain some sort of derivative. I guess I'm having a hard time seeing why $f$ can't be analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ when $\mathbb{D}$ doesn't contain any of the poles. Granted, it's easy enough to see in $\mathbb{R}$ why $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$ but if the domain of $f$ in question is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, then indeed every point $x \neq 0$ is differentiable.

Back to the initial problem I proposed, I can't see why $f$ can't be analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ when the only poles occur on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$